# Passing HTML Elements to Procedures (as parameter)

Tags: excel, vba, getelementsbytagname

I would like to call a procedure and pass some HTML elements to it.

If I call procedure this way `SimpleSearch (eNames)` then the `For Each` statement returns error

> Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Sub Navigate()    
    Set eNames = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    SimpleSearch (eNames)
End Sub


Sub SimpleSearch(ssitems)
    For Each ssitem In ssitems
        If ssitem.innerText = "Simple Search" Then
            ssitem.Focus
            ssitem.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ssitem

    Do While IE.Busy
    Loop
    Do While IE.ReadyState < 4
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If you can provide the HTML for the button it may be possible without using another sub at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis from the procedure call:

```
Sub Navigate()
    Set eNames = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    SimpleSearch eNames
End Sub
```

In VBA *functions* use parenthesis but *procedures* don't:

```
Sub Test()
    MyString = MyFunction("parameter")   'function call with parenthesis
    MyProcedure "parameter"              'procedure call without parenthesis
End Sub


Function MyFunction(Parameter As String) As String
    'some code
    MyFunction = "Return Value"   'a function should return a value
End Function

Sub MyProcedure(Parameter As String)
    'some code
End Sub
```

Comment: sure it is in the Sub, just didnt stated it in my example. Problem to solve is that procedure SimpleSearch will be not able to read the arguments as they are Html Elemetns = Type Mismatch or something similar.

Comment: OK since the code in your question is no valid VBA code please update your question including the correct code and tell exactly in which line you get which error message. Reading [mcve] might help to improve your question.

Comment: actually what you did there with the procedure call is right. The procedure arguments need to be without parenthesis : ' SimpleSearch eNames '. Just last question, why it is not working with parenthesis ? thx

Comment: sure will do so. pls update your answer to match now the question. thx